# Using a Link component with ListItem and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using material-ui v3.5.1

I want to make ListItem use the Link component like so:

```
<ListItem component={Link} to="/some/path">
  <ListItemText primary="Text" />
</ListItem>
```

but Typescript greets me with a lengthy error message (the word "component" is highlighted in VSCode), at the bottom it says:

```
The type "typeof Link" cannot be assigned to the type "ComponentClass<ListItemProps, any>"

Property 'to' is missing in type 'ListItemProps' but required in type 'Readonly'. [2322]
```

Is there a workaround to get things like these to work with Typescript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is currently a limitation of our type declarations (until we move to generic props). As a temporary workaround you can extract your link into another component e.g.

```
function SomePathLink(props: ButtonBaseProps) {
  return <Link to="/some/path" {...props} />
}

<ListItem component={SomePathLink}>
  <ListItemText primary="Text" />
</ListItem>
```

More detailed explanation in the docs: https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/#third-party-routing-library

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had to cast the ButtonBaseProps into LinkProps though:

    const SomePathLink = (eventId: string) => (props: ButtonBaseProps) => {
      return <Link to={`/events/${eventId}`} {...props as LinkProps} />
    }

Comment: What was the error? You should not cast this since this might cause runtime issues.

Comment: If I do not cast: "{ action?: ((actions: ButtonBaseActions) => void) | undefined; buttonRef?: ((instance: any) => void) | RefObject | null | undefined; centerRipple?: boolean | undefined; component?: string | ... 2 more ... | undefined; ... 274 more ...; to: string; }" cannot be assigned to type "Readonly".
property "innerRef" not comp.
The type "((instance: any) => void) | RefObject | null | undefined" cannot be assigned to type "((node: HTMLAnchorElement | null) => void) | undefined".
"null" cannot be assigned to "((node: HTMLAnchorElement | null) => void) | undefined".
[2322]"

Comment: This almost works. I'm getting this error: [...]
  Types of property 'innerRef' are incompatible.
    Type '((instance: any) => void) | RefObject<any> | null | undefined' is not assignable to type '((node: HTMLAnchorElement | null) => void) | undefined'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type '((node: HTMLAnchorElement | null) => void) | undefined'.

Comment: @Arkanoid This should be fixed in the next release. You can checkout the master build or specifically apply https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/14333 and see if that helps