# How pass params in a React Link in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, parameters, hyperlink

I'm working on a React App and I have to just change all my files from .js to .tsx

I succeeded to convert all files but I still have an error just on a Link.

Before to change my file to a .tsx, I had this code :

```
                <Link
                  to={`/items-packed/${Command_ID}`}
                  className="item"
                  params={{ Command_ID: { Command_ID } }}
                >
```

Everything was good. Now, to allow my app to work, I have to delete the line params, so I have this code :

```
                <Link
                  to={`/items-packed/${Command_ID}`}
                  className="item"
                >
```

Of course, I don't recover anything. Do you know how to pass params to a React Link in Typescript ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375964/using-a-link-component-with-listitem-and-typescript

Comment: Try this - <Link to={{ pathname:`/items-packed/${Command_ID}`, query: { Command_ID: `${Command_ID}` } }}/>

Comment: Thanks it works !